# Migration from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-luna, tomcat8

Hi I was having a maven ee project with eclipse Juno and Tomcat 7. Everything was working fine and then I moved towards up-gradation of tomcat server to tomcat 8.

Now I had to download eclipse luna so i did that and configured tomcat 8 with my project in eclipse luna. But I am getting four messages in marker.

```
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0.
JavaServer Faces 2.2 can not be installed : One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
JavaServer Faces 2.2 requires Dynamic Web Module 2.5 or newer.
One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
```

**My web.xml file is:**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">
...
</web-app>
```

**My Pom.xml file is:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>svc Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ptgoetz</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-signals</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1-incubating</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.98.4-hadoop2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>xyz/finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Plus:**

I searched a lot and messed up my web.xml and pom.xml and ./settings files as well and now I dont even remember which changes I have made but one thing i remember is that I was using servlet 2.5 in juno.

Any help in right direction would be very appreciative.

**UPDATE 1:**

Changed servlet to 3.0.1. But still getting same error

This facet.core.xml file of ./settings folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.5"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.3"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="jst.jaxrs" version="1.1"/>
  <installed facet="jboss.m2" version="1.0"/>
</faceted-project>
```

When i change jst.web to 3.0 then i get error again cannot change project facet web dynamic version to 3.0

Comment: Just a quick observation your web.xml defines version 3.0 but your servlet dependency is still 2.5, does upgrading your servlet dependency version to 3.0 help? Also try going to Project properties/Facets in Eclipse and set the Facet web version to 3.0 manually after you update your dependencies.

Comment: Delete the project from Eclipse and import it again.

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt Do you mean changing Dynamic Web Module to 3.0? Because after going to project properties->Facets I cannot see Facet Web version.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I did that but it not worked.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

It should be 3.0 at least since your web.xml specifies `version="3.0"`. But maintaining this dependency may give you conflicts with Java EE 7.0 dependency here:

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Looks like you're just copying/pasting/crossing your fingers and hoping that everything works. This is not how you're supposed to do it. Just import the relevant dependencies you will use.

Comment: I have changed the servlet dependency to 3.0 but its still not working.

Comment: Now its saying cannot change version of Dynamic Web Module to 3.0

Comment: @Mr37037 are you sure your project is a Maven project rather than a dynamic web project?

Comment: Yeah I did it like open eclipse luna-> file-> import -> existing maven project. btw this maven project was working fine in juno with tomcat 7.

Comment: I have added facets file as well

Answer (score 0):

Just Solved the errors by adding this to pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```